# In selection sort, if we have two duplicate elements, what is the behavior of the algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

If we delete the part starting with `if (indexMax != i)` from the code below (the last part) the Algoritm shatters, why?

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int indexMax = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[indexMax] < array[j]) {
                indexMax = j;
            }
        }

        if (indexMax != i) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[indexMax];
            array[indexMax] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what that part does?

Comment: That part of the algorithm is the part that actually swaps the Max with the current index in order to sort it...

Comment: cause that's the part that makes the permutations? Your question is unclear. You can't remove random part of a code and expect it to still work the same way

Comment: To answer the question from the title: give it a try, it's way faster than waiting for an answer

Comment: if (indexMax != i) is just betterment of the algo .. if you debug it with already sorted array it will never get called ,.. hence you save the swapping.

Comment: My question is how do the algorithm work if we have two duplicates in the array

Comment: Please don't use tag as you like. android tag has nothing to do with this.

Comment: What does "shatters" mean in this context? The algorithm should work just fine if the swap between indices `i` and `indexMax` is unconditional. Of course, if you delete the code doing that swap entirely then the algorithm does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would do the following:

```
arr[] = 1, 5, 2, 4, 3

// find the max from arr[0..4]
// substitute it with the index 0, if it is not of that index already
arr[] = 5, 1, 2, 4, 3

// find the max from arr[1..4]
// substitute it with the index 1, if it is not of that index already
arr[] = 5, 4, 2, 1, 3 

// find the max from arr[2..4]
// substitute it with the index 2, if it is not of that index already 
arr[] = 5, 4, 3, 1, 2

// find the max from arr[3..4]
// substitute it with the index 3, if it is not of that index already 
arr[] = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

The *substitute it with the index `i`, if it is not of that index already* is that `if` statement

---

For a longer array, with duplicates, check this [Kotlin Playground Code](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) I created for you. You can change the array as you wish, and you can trace the switching of the values.

Comment: Please give an example with two duplicate elements @Nizar

Comment: Alright, I'll update my answer with a duplicate element. Be right back.

Comment: I updated my answer for you Hadi, kindly check it. As PM mentioned, if two elements are equal then the `arr[m] < arr[j]` would return `false`; therefore, the swap will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted with my comments:

```
    int indexMax = i;  // initial value of indexMax

    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        // please note that j starts with (i+1)
        if (array[indexMax] < array[j]) {
            indexMax = j;  // index of Max candidate  
        }
    }

    if (indexMax != i) {   // means that the above loop reassigned indexMax
        int temp = array[i];  // so we are swapping
        array[i] = array[indexMax];
        array[indexMax] = temp;
    }
```

So `if (indexMax != i)` means "*Did we find a better Max?*"

Comment: My question is how do the algorithm work if we have two duplicates in the array  please trace for me :0

Comment: For tracing in your case please use a debugger with step-by-step execution.

Comment: If two elements are equal than `array[indexMax] < array[j]` will be `false` and no swap will happen.

Answer (score -1):

In the picture you can see how duplicate items move their relative position.This introduce instability.

For three duplicate items:

[image: 3 duplicate item]

For two duplicate items:

[image: 2 duplicate item]

Comment: I think you got voted down because you have this backwards. It is sorting largest to the left. Other than that, I love that you drew it out. The other ones are more accurate but for people that are visual and still trying to understand code, this is a great description. @ me if you change it so that the array becomes largest to smallest and I'll up-vote your answer. (Take a look at the Kotlin link in the accepted answer)